# Can my employer make me to pay for their tax mistake from my future paychecks?

Tags: benefits, taxes-owing

I live and work in the same building. As part of my employee benefits, I pay no rent for my apartment.  However, I pay 30% tax on the rent at the time I signed the lease.

Without my knowledge, my employer failed to tax me correctly for the years of 2010, 2011 and 6 months of 2012.

They recently discovered their mistake and now they want me to make it up and pay 30% tax on over $38,000. They want to deduct $150 from the next 78 paychecks and I'm paid biweekly. Can my employer do this?

Comment: This is where??

Comment: It sounds like they failed to bill you in the past and are now catching up.  You're just losing a free ride you had.

Comment: You'll need to tell us where you are.  Tax and law questions require a country tag.

Comment: What does "I **pay** 30% tax on the rent" mean? Is this tax that is _withheld_ by your employer from your paycheck? What does "my employer failed to tax me correctly" mean? Unless your employer is the government, your employer cannot _tax_ you; the employer can withhold tax from your salary and send it to the government (as the employer is usually required to do by law) but then the employer is also required to tell the government that salary (plus benefits) in the amount of X was paid and tax in the amount of Y was withheld and sent in.

Comment: Do you live and work in the same building for your own benefit or for your employer's benefit? It makes a huge difference.

Answer (score 4):

(I am making the assumption that this is a US based question).

Keep in mind that the alternative is to amend your tax forms from 2010, and 2011. The IRS and the State will want their money, they might not to wait for 78 paychecks. That is 3 years.

Ask for lots of documentation, so you understand what they are doing.

Comment: Yes the alternative is to catch it all up out of savings immediately since the benefit was received the taxes were not paid, it might even cost the OP penalties and interest.

Comment: In the US, if you approach the IRS they are willing to work with you.  They *will* collect their money, but you can make a plan to pay it back however works best for you.  Start early and be consistent if you have to deal with the IRS.

Comment: IRS allows payment plans, especially for people who have no recent non-compliance issues (you get a payment plan approved automatically if you haven't had one in the last 5 years and you're in compliance).

Answer (score 2):

I assume the OP is the US and that he is, like most people, a cash-basis
tax payer and not an accrual basis tax payer.

- Suppose the value of the rental of the unit the OP is occupying 
  **was reported 
  as income** on the OP's 2010 and 2011 W-2 forms but the **corresponding income 
  tax was not withheld**.  If the OP correctly transcribed these income numbers
  onto his tax returns, correctly computed the tax on the income reported
  on his 2010 and 2011 1040 forms, and paid the amount due in timely fashion, 
  then there is no
  tax or penalty due for 2010 and 2011. Nor is the company entitled to withhold
  tax on this income for 2010 and 2011 at this time; the tax on that income
  has already been paid by the OP directly to the IRS and the company has
  nothing to do with the matter anymore.
- Suppose the value of the rental of the unit the OP is occupying 
  **was NOT reported as income** on the OP's 2010 and 2011 W-2 forms. 
  If the OP correctly transcribed these income numbers
  onto his tax returns, correctly computed the tax on the income reported
  on his 2010 and 2011 1040 forms, and paid the amount due in timely fashion, 
  then there is no tax or penalty due for 2010 and 2011. **Should** the OP
  have declared the value of the rental of the unit as additional income
  from his employer that was not reported on the W-2 form, and paid taxes 
  on that money? Possibly, but it would be reasonable to argue that the OP
  did nothing wrong other than not checking his W-2 form carefully: he simply
  assumed the income numbers included the value of the rental and copied
  whatever the company-issued W-2 form said onto his 1040 form. At least as 
  of now, there is no reason for the IRS to question his 2010 and 2011 returns
  because the numbers reported to the IRS on Copy A of the W-2 forms match
  the numbers reported by the OP on his tax returns.

My guess is that the company discovered that it had not actually declared
the value of the rental payments on the OP's W-2 forms for 2010 and 2011
and now wants to include this amount as income on subsequent W-2 forms.
Now, reporting a lump-sum benefit of $38K (but no actual cash) 
would have caused a *huge* amount of income tax to need to be withheld,
and the OP's next couple of paychecks might well have had *zero
take-home pay* as all the money was going towards this tax withholding.
Instead, the company is saying that it will report the $38K as
income in 78 equal installments (weekly paychecks over 18 months?) 
and withhold $150 as
the tax due on each installment. If it does not already do so,
it will likely also include the
value of the *current* rent as a benefit and withhold tax on that
too. So the OP's take-home pay will reduce by $150 (at least)
and maybe more if the current rental payments also start appearing
on the paychecks and tax is withheld from them too.

I will not express an opinion on the legality of the company
withholding an additional $150 as tax from the OP's paycheck,
but will suggest that the solution proposed by the company
(have the money appear as taxable benefits over a 78-week
period, have tax withheld, and declare the income on your 
2012, 2013 and 2014 returns) is *far* more beneficial to the
OP than the company declaring to the IRS that it made a 
mistake on the 2010 and 2011 W-2's issued to the OP, and
that the actual income paid was higher. Not only will the OP
have to file amended returns for 2010 and 2011 but the company
will need to amend its tax returns too.

In summary, the OP needs to know that

> - He will have to pay taxes on the value of the waived rental payments
>     for 2010 and 2011.
> - The company's mistake in not declaring this as income to the OP
>     for 2010 and 2011 does not absolve him of the responsibility
>     for paying the taxes
> - What the company is proposing is a very reasonable solution to the
>     problem of recovering from the mistake.
> - The alternative, as @mhoran_psprep points out, is to amend
>     your 2010 and 2011 federal and state tax returns to declare the
>     value of the rental during those years as additional income,
>     and pay taxes (and possibly penalties) on the additional
>     amount due. This takes the company completely out of the picture,
>     but does require a lot more work and a lot more cash now rather
>     than in the future.